# Difference between cascade and cascode?

Tags: schematics, amplifier, cascode

What is the difference between cascode amplifier configuration and cascade amplifier configuration?

Answer (score 10):

From a transistor perspective, a cascade is typically when the amplifier load(s) are connected in a left-to right horizontal chain configuration, whereas a cascode has the load(s) stacked vertically.

Examples...
[image]

edit. whoops, I somehow linked on an older post. Sorry if it is out of place.

Answer (score 7):

In a cascade:
the output of the first amplifying device (transistor) is fed as input to the second amplifying device,
whose output is fed as input to the third,
and so on until an adequate signal amplification has been achieved.
[Cascade](http://www.innovatia.com/Design_Center/Amplifier_Circuits.htm)

Cascode:
An amplifier consisting of a common emitter input stage that drives a common base output stage.
advantages include high gain and low noise.
[Cascode](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_4/8.html)

Go through these links you may get an clear idea about these.

Comment: Can you give some example circuits? Seems like a great way to cement your answer. The only other thing after that I could want would be references for further learning. Thank you for writing an answer!

Comment: @Kortuk:Go through those above links as i changed added it in my answer as per your request

Comment: Section 3: "Cascading Cascode amplifiers!" You seem to be a new user, please do not take my guidance incorrectly, it is meant as helpful advice, nothing more.

Comment: @Kortuk"Cascading Cascode amplifier!" i didn't get your point.

Comment: That was a joke. I was just pointing out, you can cascade cascode amplifiers, you could even cascode two sets of cascaded amplifiers. Something to think about for those that do not understand what they are. Thanks for the edits!

Comment: @Kortuk: ha ha its an joke but thanks for your information.

Comment: Links aren't answers.  This has a little bit more content than just a link, but not much.